# How to prove that a given map is an injection?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

Let $g:\mathbb{N_{m_1-1}}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}_{m_1}$, where:

$$g(i) = \left\{ \begin{align} i & \text {, for }   i<i_0 \\
i+1 & \text{, for }  i \ge i_0
\end{align}\right.$$

and $i_0 \in \mathbb{N_{m_1}}$, $m_1 \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

The notations are explained in more detail in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877078/help-to-clarify-inductive-step-for-proof-of-mathbbn-m-rightarrow-mathbbn) question (Case 2).

I need to show that $g(i)$ is injective. So I need to show that $g(i_1)=g(i_2) \Rightarrow i_1=i_2$.

So, if $g(i_1) = g(i_2)$, then the following cases can happen:

1. $i_1 = i_2$, if $i_1 < i_0$ and $i_2<i_0$
2. $i_1+1 = i_2+1$, if $i_1 \ge i_0$ and $i_2 \ge i_0$
3. $i_1 = i_2+1,$ if $i_1 < i_0$ and $i_2 \ge i_0$
4. $i_1+1=i_2,$  if $i_1 \ge i_0$ and $i_2 < i_0$

It is easy to show that cases 1 and 2 implies the $i_1=i_2$.

How do I deal with cases 3 and 4? Do I need to argue that cases 3 and 4 do not imply $g(i_1)=g(i_2)$ or do I just simply ignore them?

Comment: what is $\Bbb N_{\mathrm m}$?

Comment: Case 3 and 4 can't happen: for example if $i_1 = i_2 + 1$, then $i_0 \le i_2 < i_1 < i_0$ is a contradiction.

Comment: @Ilya It is the set of natural numbers, where $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. I've updated my question with this addition.

Comment: still not getting that, if it is *the* set of natural numbers, how does it depend on $m$?

Comment: @Ilya this is actually part of a larger question. The claim is that for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, we can construct an injective function $g:\mathbb{N}_{m-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}_m$

Comment: Even if it is a part of a larger question, either put a link to that question (in case $\Bbb N_m$ is defined there), or define it here, please. Do you mean that $\Bbb N_m = \{m,m+1,\dots\}$ or it's something different?

Comment: @Ilya Sorry, turns out I made alot of typos. This is the larger question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877078/help-to-clarify-inductive-step-for-proof-of-mathbbn-m-rightarrow-mathbbn Please refer to Case 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your argument. You should look at $g(i)$ compared to $g(i_0)$, which reduced the number of cases to 2:

- if $g(i_1)=g(i_2)=g(i)<i_0$, then $i<i_0$ as $g$ is strictly increasing. Then you know that $i_1=g(i_1)=g(i_2)=i_2$.
- same goes for $g(i_1)=g(i_2)=g(i)>i_0$ $i_1+1=g(i_1)=g(i_2)=i_2+1$.
- there is no case $g(i_0)=i_0$ by definition of your function

In all cases, $g(i_1)=g(i_2) \Rightarrow i_1=i_2$